# SQL Server 2005 full database backup to disk

Tags: sql-server, remote-backup

I'm trying to do a full backup of my database by entering the following:

```
BACKUP DATABASE 10997_diamondtransportinccom
TO DISK = 'D:\10997diamond.BAK';
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '10997'.

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [10997_diamondtransportinccom] TO DISK = 'D:\10997diamond.BAK'
```

[Note: square brackets]

See [Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Comment: Because 10997_diamondtransportinccom is not a valid SQL identifier and so must be quoted. I figure someone will ask why, so I thought I would answer.

Comment: actually. isn't the problem the leading digit on the identifier?